# Android: List all file in a directory

Tags: java, android, list, file, directory

I'm trying to build an application that lists all files in a directory and allows the user tap a file and have it open in a specific app depending on the file extension. So far, I've written this code to list all the files in the directory but it doesn't seem to work - it just crashes the application.

Could anyone advise why please? I've tried to replicate other code snippets I've found on SO and other various places, but none seem to work.

Thanks in advance

```
String home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/vuza/" + username;
Toast.makeText(this, "Debug: " + home, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

File root = new File(home);

File fileList[] = root.listFiles();

for(int x = 0; x < fileList.length; x++) {
    Toast.makeText(this, fileList[x].getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

EDIT: Added stack-trace

```
04-08 19:29:39.230    5264-5264/com.mikekaperys.assignment E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mikekaperys.assignment, PID: 5264
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mikekaperys.assignment/com.mikekaperys.assignment.Files}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mikekaperys.assignment.Files.onCreate(Files.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add your stack trace?

Comment: Post the crash logs, so that it will be easy to get the issue.

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Comment: What's the result of `root.exists()`?

Comment: Added stack-trace/logcat. Sorry, new to Android!

Comment: What is line 32 of com.mikekaperys.assignment.Files? That's where the crash is occuring.

Comment: if (fileList==null){toast dir does not contain files; return;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Put this in manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

**2)** Also check if that `home` path exists.

**3)** `fileList.length` may return null if no directory is in there. Check if `fileList` is null before `loop`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code  with below one

```
String home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/vuza/" + username;
```

File file = new File(home);

```
if(file.exists())
{
//method call
    listf(home);
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(this,"no dir extists"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public File[] listf(String directoryName) {

    // .............list file
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fList);
    return fList;
}
```

also make sure you have given following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```